# MVC - Design Pattern for centralized dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Normally we have something similar to the following logic:

```
public class DummyController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var model = new TestViewModel
        {
            Selected = "2",
            // NOTE: i can use a service to fill it with DB values
            OptionsSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Option 1", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Option 2", Value = "2"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Option 3", Value = "3"}
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(e=> e.Selected, Model.OptionsSelectList);
```

Now I am trying to apply the concept of **Single responsibility principle** to this situation.

I might have several places where I need to render the same dropdown in so many places and I do not want to keep copy/paste this block of code in every single controller actions where I need to use it.

So, first I thought of creating an **EditorTemplate** (MVC Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DummyOptionsSelectList.cshtml), where the received model is matching the data type of that property, example `int?` or `string` or something else. But now I am in a view where I need to access C# services in order to reach the Database (not even counting extra logic as filtering the data according to user permissions, etc...).... then I thought this is not the best approach.

Then a second approach was using a custom **HTML Helper** to accomplish this... because then I am inside of a class and not on a view.... easier to reach a DB service layer.

But... I still see some issues with this approach....

Other option that is providing me all what I am looking for is to fill the dropwdown using Javascript on the client side (by retrieving the data always by need)... but this approach has the disadvantage by "exposing" somehow my own API, and also to force a new http request per dropdown box that my page has.....

**I was wondering what other solutions do you guys/gals use for this?**

Things to keep in mind:

- Centralized logic for each dropdown type
- Returned data can be different based on user permissions, etc (I need to take in consideration that I need to access the current user Id, or some other necessary info)
- the "isSelected" value still needs to work
- The id/name of the html element still needs to match all the other form inputs similar to when I use `Html.EditorFor(m=> m.MyObject.Child.PropertyValueId,...)` and not lose all this "train of property names"

Comment: Do you need to load the available options from the DB? Or would a fixed set of options (e.g. defined by an enum) work for you?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider in this specific case it comes from the DB. Regarding processing "static content" lists or enums to dropdowns, I have it managed already :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use a combination of the ways I pointed out in the question text.

**EditorTemplate**: for "static" lists or enumeration based

**HTML Helper**: for DB content that might has privacy issues or even "filters as parameters" that I do not want to make it visible. Probably NO cache on this data (case by case situations)

**Ajax filled dropdowns**: for DB content I do not care if the filter parameters are known to the user or not (no security breach), and data can even be cached without concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would do is to use the Repository Pattern.
You could make e repository with a specific method that queries the database and returns the data for that dropdown list. You could add parameters to that specific method, so you could change the data slightly, depending on the specific situation. Then in the controller you just initialize the repository and invoke the method, assign the data to a view model property and return a view.